# jQuery or PHP: Comparing Documents

Tags: php, jquery, compare, documents

Just wondering if anyone can suggest a tool (either jquery or php) that allows document comparison?  The documents are stored in MySQL (if that's relevant).

I've googled it, and found a couple of things (looks like there's something for jquery, but it's under development?).  In any case, maybe my search terms aren't great, so, was hoping to get some suggestions...

**EDIT
Just as a follow-up... I wound up using http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API
It's fast and simple!**

Comment: What kind of documents are you talking about? And what kind of comparison? Are you looking for diff tools?

Comment: Ah, sorry... I need something basic that will highlight changes between two fields.  (Like MS Word... with redlining...) Essentially, a user submits a form.  An editor goes in and changes it, and then the user can go in and compare their submission to the changed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a handy javascript lib for finding diffs on a line by line basis and viewing them in html

https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib

Comment: I liked this one very much, but wound up using the tool mentioned above.  Thank you!